# Is there a way to plot a point name in Octave?

Tags: plot, label, octave

I want to plot two points on a graph and that's what I managed to do.

But I want next to the first point to be written x0 and next to the second point x1.
Is there a way to give a point a label or rather a name in Octave?
Here is the image of my plot:

[image]

As you can see the two dots don't have a label. And here is the code:

```
  x0 = [5,10];
  x1 = [-1.75, 0];
  hold on;
  plot(x0(1), x0(2), 'x')
  plot(x1(1), x1(2), 'x')
  hold off;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `text` function:

```
x0 = [5,10];
x1 = [-1.75, 0];
hold on;
plot(x0(1), x0(2), 'x')
plot(x1(1), x1(2), 'x')
text(x0(1), x0(2), "point 0")
text(x1(1), x1(2), "point 1")
hold off;
```

If you need to adjust the font size, just call it as

```
text(x1(1), x1(2), "point 1","fontsize",<your_font_size>)
```